# Как сгруппировать данные в списке по условию?

Tags: c#, list

Есть класс `DB`. Я его использую в списке `List<DB>`. Хочу сгруппировать данные по элементам где `ParentId=0`, но не пойму как добавить условие к группировке

```
class DB
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string  Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: 1) `ParentId=0` у вас ParentId - строка в классе, а не число 2) `сгруппировать данные по элементам где ParentId=0` - вы путаете наверное группировку и фильтрацию.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов возвращать уже готовый, сгруппированный список из базы, а так же можно применить linq-запрос с orderby к Вашему списку. 
Пример
 есть уже готовые данные из бд в listDataWthisDB и применить linq.
listDataWthisDB.GroupBy(p => p.ParentId ) пример показывает вариант группировки образно.